# PostgreSQL, stored procedure para actualizar una tabla

Tags: sql, postgresql

Estoy creando una *stored procedure* para actualizar el dato `userid` de la tabla `clients` en base al *id* del cliente `cid`; pero hasta ahora no he tenido éxito: la función no actualiza el `userid` del client.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION updateclient_uid(cid text,uid text)   RETURNS void AS 
$BODY$
BEGIN
    UPDATE  clients
    SET userid = '@uid' 
    WHERE clientid = '@cid'; 
END;
$BODY$   
LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE   
COST 100; 
ALTER FUNCTION updateclient_uid(text, text)   
OWNER TO postgres;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

en realidad eso no es un stored procedure sino una función. Aunque en postgres son algo parecido a lo que en otros motores es un SP, recién en PG 11 habrá soporte para stored procedures.

Dicho esto, lo que estás haciendo no usa la sintaxis correcta. Debiera ser, en cambio:

```
BEGIN
    UPDATE  clients
    SET userid = uid 
    WHERE clientid = cid; 
END;
```